# how YARN handles name node failures

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a doubt regarding how **YARN** handles "NAME NODE" failures? OR did **YARN** come up with Single point of failure (**NameNode**)?

Answer (score 4):

Yarn is the improved version of mapreduce framework, it's a generic framework for handling different kinds of jobs not only limited to mapreduce,

Namenode is an HDFS component, it's a separate component. There is not direct connection between Yarn and HDFS except Yarn can access HDFS.

Namenode high availability is not related to yarn.

Comment: Thanks for the your reply. You mean with YARN also Hadoop is still single point of faliure right? i heard some thing like active & passive name nodes... is that not realtes to YARN am i right?

Comment: Namenode high availability is not related to yarn.